# Find highest value with Collection.max() in HashSet

Tags: java, bluej

This is coded in BlueJ!

Hi guys, I am trying to find a max value in a HashSet. I'm trying to use the Collection.max method, but it's not working for me. I'm getting an error: no suitable method found for max(int). The error is in my VerhuurderBedrijf class, the last method called getLongestRentPeriod.

I have 2 classes, (it's dutch) VerhuurderBedrijf and Container.
In the Container class, I have a method called differenceInDays. Here it calculates the difference in days between the startDate and endDate (see fields in Container class).

In the VerhuurderBedrijf I am adding the Container objects in a HashSet. In my getLongestRentPeriod, I'm trying to find the highest value calculated in my differenceInDays method(Container class).

Lets say I add 2 container objects in my VerhuurderBedrijf class.
Container 1 - startDate = 10-10-2014; endDate = 15-10-2014;
Container 2 - startDate = 10-10-2014; endDate = 20-10-2014;
As I said, the difference in days is calculated in my differenceInDatys method (Container class)/

So with my getLongestRentPeriode(verhuurderbedrijf class) I am trying to get the highest value, that would be 11 days (Container 2);

Sorry if it's unclear. I am bad in explaining things.

Here is the full code.

**VerhuurderBedrijf class**

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
    
public class VerhuurderBedrijf
{
    private HashSet<Container> containerList;
    // Decimalen object
    DecimalFormat df;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class VerhuurderBedrijf
     */
    public VerhuurderBedrijf()
    {
        containerList = new HashSet<Container>();
        // Dit zorgt ervoor dat er 2 decimalen achter de komma komen
        df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    }
    
    public void addContainer(Container container)
    {
        // Voegt een container toe een de HashSet<Container>
        containerList.add(container);
    }
        
    public void gettotalIncome()
    {
        double total = 0;
        for(Container container : containerList)
        {
            total += container.getIncome();
        }
        System.out.println("The total amount of income for the rented containers are:\r\n " + (df.format(total)) + " euros.\r\n");
    }
        
    public void getAverageVolume()
    {
        double average = 0;
        double calc = 0;
        for(Container container : containerList)
        {
            average += container.getVolume();
            calc = average / containerList.size();
        }
        System.out.println("The average volume of the rented container are:\r\n " + (df.format(calc)) + ".\r\n");
    }
        
    public void getLongestRentPeriod()
    {       
        for(Container container : containerList)
        {
            System.out.println("max : " + Collections.max(container.differenceInDays()));
        }
    }
}
```

**Container class**

```java
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
    
public class Container
{
    private int volume;
    private String startDate;
    private String endDate;
    // Tijd object
    SimpleDateFormat format;
    
    public Container(int volume, String startDate, String endDate)
    {
        this.volume = volume;
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.endDate = endDate;
        // Dit zet de datum om naar een ddmmjjjj formaat, zo is het mogelijk om bijv: 12102014 in te vullen
        format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    }
        
    public int getCosts()
    {
        int cost1 = 60;
        int cost2 = 125;
        if(volume <= 2)
        {
            // Als de volume kleiner of gelijk is aan 2, zijn de kosten voor de container 60 euro
            return cost1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Anders zijn de kosten voor de container 125 euro
            return cost2;
        }
    }
        
    public int differenceInDays()
    {
        int startDateCheck = Integer.parseInt(startDate);
        int endDateCheck = Integer.parseInt(endDate);
        if(startDateCheck > endDateCheck)
        {
            // Als er een verkeerde invoer wordt gedaan
            System.out.println("Your end date cannot be earlier than your start date");
        }
        else
        {
            // Try & Catch omdat er een error ParseException komt, Date is een long in plaats van een String
            try
            {
                String start = startDate;
                String end = endDate;
                    
                Date day1 = format.parse(start);
                Date day2 = format.parse(end);
                    
                long difference = day2.getTime() - day1.getTime();
                /*
                Verschil in de dagen die hierboven wordt uitgerekend, wordt hier omgezet naar de aantal
                dagen. 24 = uren, 60 = minuten, 60 = seconden, 1000 = milliseconden
                */
                long differenceInDays = difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) + 1;
                // Hier cast ik het naar een int, omdat het een public int methode is
                int castToInt = (int) differenceInDays;     
                return castToInt;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
        
    public int getIncome()
    {
        int rent = 40;
        // (Huur container * de ingevoerde volume) + (Huur container * verschil in de dagen)
        int income = (rent * volume) + (rent * differenceInDays());
        return income;
    }
        
    public int getVolume()
    {
        return volume;
    }
}
```

I also tried this, but it's not working either. I am getting a value of 72, whats not the right number.

```java
public void getLongestRentPeriod()
{   
    int temp = 0;
    for(Container container : containerList)
    {
        if(temp < container.differenceInDays())
        {
            temp = container.differenceInDays();
        }
        //System.out.println("max : " + Collections.max(container.differenceInDays()));
    }
    System.out.println("max: " + temp);        
}
```

Could anyone give me some tips or suggestions for the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The error message says it all:

> no suitable method found for max(int)

So, you want to use a method max, taking a Collection as argument, but what you're passing to the method is not a Collection, it's an int:

```
Collections.max(container.differenceInDays())
```

with `differenceInDays()` being defined as

```
public int differenceInDays()
```

I assume that what you want is to find the `Container`, inside the set `containerList`, that has the greatest differenceInDays. So you need to call

```
Collections.max(containerList, comparatorComparingContainersByDifferenceInDays)
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want to find, but your solution is not working for me. It says: cannot find symbol- variable comparatorComparingContainersByDifferenceInDays. I dont quite understand this line of code tho.

Comment: You're supposed to write a Comparator<Container>, that takes two containers, and compares them by their difference in days. Look at the javadoc. Google for "compare objects in Java". Look at the javadoc of Collections.max().

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 you could do the following:

```
OptionalInt max = containerList.stream().mapToInt(Container::differenceInDays).max();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
Collections.max(container.differenceInDays())
```

Where your max method takes collection as parameter.see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29

So if you make your Container implement Comparable and if you try

```
Container container = Collections.max(containerList);//without for loop
```

Container will hold max of all container. Or if Container is third party, i would sugges you creating a static class (or anonymous class) with compare method by implementing Comparator interface. something like

```
private class ContainerComparator implements Comparator<Container> {
    public int compare(Container o1, Container o2) {
        //here calculate diff of each and send difference between the two
    }
}
```

Comment: I only need to get the max of differenceInDays(), not the max of containerList.